# what is wrong with my code. I am not getting required output. when in executed this code in one of the online compiler it is no giving required output

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    int age;
    printf("enter your age:");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    
    if(age>=18 || age<=70){
        printf("you can drive");
    }else{
        printf("you cannot drive");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**I am not getting the required output
"enter your age:you can drive"**

Comment: `if(age>=18 && age<=70)`

Comment: `||` = one or another. `&&` = one and another

Answer (score 0):

If you use `||` your range will be open.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this condition instead: `if(age>=18 && age<=70)`